# What sci-fi series used an alien weapon that disabled the ship when fired?

Tags: story-identification, weapon

I vaguely remember a sci-fi series that had a spaceship that used an alien weapon.

When this weapon was used it caused the ship (computer?) to power down for a minute or so and so they were vulnerable... or would have been if the weapon didn't work.

Any ideas as to the series name?

Comment: Any other details you can remember? Was this in the 80's? 90's? U.S.? British? Animated? Live action?

Comment: Could it be Farscape? Moya was the live ship.

Comment: @Willow - That wasn't a weapon though

Comment: @Valorum you're right -- her son had them but it did not harm him to use them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is *Crusade*, a short-lived spin-off of Babylon 5.

From Wikipedia:

> Excalibur features energy and particle beam weapons. The main guns operate at two main power levels. "Level One" provides beams with little more firepower than a White Star. "Level Two" is much more powerful weapon, reverse engineered from Vorlon lightning cannon technology. [...] Firing this titanic weapon drains all the ship's power and the "Excalibur" is unable to maneuver, fire weapons or use long-range scanners for approximately one minute afterward.

Comment: Crusade was going to be my suggestion as well, unless we're talking about anime, in which case it could be Space Battleship Yamato, which was also vulnerable after firing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Battleship_Yamato_(fictional_spacecraft)

Comment: Yes, it does sound like Crusade.  I'll check it out now.
Many thanks.